# Socket Can connect locally, but not remotely even though it was connecting

Tags: c#, sockets

2 days ago it was working, but it just stop to work, take a look

**Server:**

```
 IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 50000);
        Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            listener.Bind(endpoint);
            listener.Listen(100);
```

Client: (192.168.0.2 work because it's local, but when I try with my ip from "www.whatismyip.com" I can't connect)

```
 IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.2"), 50000);

        cliente = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        cliente.Connect(ipEndPoint);
```

My firewall is disabled and I did portforward at 50000

Comment: Do you get an exception?  If so what is the exception type and message?

Comment: I get a SocketException that say I couldn't connect because the host didn't answer

Comment: Are you on corporate network? If so, corporate is likely blocking external connections on that port.  If it is on your home network, when you mention firewall - is it Windows Firewall, or is it router firewall (and of course, check the other).

Comment: Windows firewall is disabled, and I'm at home

Comment: @user3666414 what about your router firewall?

Comment: I tried to disable it and didn't work as well

Comment: Trying using Telnet to connect `telnet 192.168.0.2 50000`.  If you get denied right away, the server is not accepting the connection.  If takes more than 2-3 seconds to timeout, it would most likely be a Firewall issue.

Comment: @user3666414 But did you set up port forwarding on your router? I.e. external ip 50000 forward to 192.168.0.2 50000.

Comment: Yes, I did set up my port forwarding on my router

Comment: @user3666414 B/w, when replying in comments to someone else's comment, please put `@user` (like this comment starts) to notify them. Otherwise they may not see your reply.

Comment: @user3666414 Hmm... does your ISP allow for external connections? Do you have any other services on that machine that you connect to from outside (like ftp, http, etc..)?

Comment: @LB2 Yeah it allow, actually the same code was working 2 days ago, I just tested it with my friend, but today when I tried to test again, it was only working locally, even if I try to run the server and client app at the same PC it just work with local ip

Answer (score 0):

Good news and bad news. The good news is that it's probably not you. The bad news is there's probably nothing you can do about it other than change what you're trying to do. The odds are your connection requests are getting dropped in one of two places - either by your (DSL, cable, etc.) modem or by your ISP. When you get your external IP address and then try to connect back to it, the modem gets confused since it seems to be trying to send something to itself, but not via a loopback interface, and so discards the TCP SYN packet. Alternatively, your ISP has you behind some sort of NAT and what you think is your external IP address does not match what your ISP's router believes is your (regional) address. This is also confusing and the packet is either dropped or forwarded to the global version of your address. Maybe it gets there, maybe not. Either way the connection is lost in the ether.

You say the same code worked with your friend 2 days ago. Clearly something is different between his internet connection and yours.

Comment: And what was the result? Often devices get confused when they see a destination address that matches the sending interface. One thing to try is to run a traceroute to that destination address and see what happens.